# Button padding attribute being ignored in XML layout

Tags: android

I'm trying to setup a layout of 6 buttons in the form of 2x3 (w/h) on the screen.

My layout XML is below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/androidbg"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/none"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/none"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/none"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/none"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTopLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/diary"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:onClick="openDiary"
                android:padding="4dip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTopRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/diary"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:onClick="openDiary"
                android:padding="4dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMidLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/diary"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:onClick="openDiary"
                android:padding="4dip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMidRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/diary"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:onClick="openDiary"
                android:padding="4dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnBottomLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/diary"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:onClick="openDiary"
                android:padding="4dip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnBottomRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/diary"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:onClick="openDiary"
                android:padding="4dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```

This XML mostly works as I want it to - with the exception of the `android:padding="4dip"` inside the `<Button>` tags. This padding seems to be being completely ignored, making the buttons squashed together in the middle.

Below I have provided a crude drawing (behold my paint skills) of the current state of the app on the left - and the intended layout of the app on the right (blue boxes are buttons).

[image: Current vs Intended layout]

Any ideas how I would be able to pad the buttons apart in the center?

Comment: you are confusing `margin` with `padding`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add `margin` instead of `padding`, it's up to you where the margin have to be applied (`layout_marginLeft` or `layout_marginRight`) but this should solve your problem:

```
android:layout_margin="4dp"
```

instead of

```
android:padding="4dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using too many layouts here!

You need a parent `RelativeLayout`. Inside it, add the first button, `Button1`. Then the second button will be placed `toRightOf: Button1` with the padding you need (`android:marginLeft = xdp`), aligned at the top.

Similarly, the third button will be `toBottomOf: Button1` with the padding, and aligned at the left side. Etcetera...

Comment: That's the method I was using before, and found that it did not scale well when testing it on multiple devices. The `android:weight` attribute of the `LinearLayout` allows me to fit the buttons in the exact pattern I want whilst keeping it scaled properly across various screen sizes.

Comment: Using your suggested method, how would you suggest I resize the buttons based on the screen size? I'm interested to know, as I may use your suggestion if I can size the buttons properly.

Comment: In that case, implement the exact RelativeLayout that I've told you, only with `wrap_content` for both its dimensions, and place it inside another RelativeLayout with `match_parent` and gravity `center`